# How to generate wordclouds next to each other in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, word-cloud

I have the following code that generates t figures with wordclouds:

```
    for t in range(n_components):
        plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(lda_top_words[t]))
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.title("Topic #" + str(t))
        plt.show()
```

How can I change this to generate one figure with multiple plots in the same figure?

Comment: check out `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots` https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: Do I have to define the number shape of the subplots from the start or can I create them one after the other inside the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using subplots and the following code:

```
def display_wordcloud(top_words, title, n_components):
    plt.figure()
    j = np.ceil(n_components/4)
    for t in range(n_components):
        i=t+1
        plt.subplot(j, 4, i).set_title("Topic #" + str(t))
        plt.plot()
        plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(top_words[t]))
        plt.axis("off")
    fig.suptitle(title)
    plt.show()
```

Here n_components are the number of plots I want to see and also the number of different topics in my topic model. 
Top_words are the top Words from each topic in my topic model
And tile is the title i want for my figure

This code display 4 plots in each row.